# Issue with translucent navigation and opaque status bar

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat

I have an Android app, I want to have translucent navigation buttons (when the device has software nav buttons), while keeping opaque status and action bars.

All my activities' layouts should therefore expand under the navigation bar but not under the status and action bars.

I have implemented the following theme for API 19+ devices:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
    <item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">false</item>
</style>
```

As expected, the navigation bar becomes translucent and the status /action bars remain opaques. But all my layouts now expand beneath the action and status bars! Even though they are not translucent!

Any ideas?
Setting `fitsSystemWindows=true` in the theme does not correct the issue...

Comment: Try adding fitsSystemWindow in the first viewgroup of your view

Comment: You got any solution ?